# Calling contract from contract not working

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp

below are very simple setup of one contract calling another contract and I somehow can't get it to work.

Contract C1

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract C1 {
    int public x = 1;

    function setX(int _x) public {
        x = _x;
    }

    function getX() public view returns (int y) {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Contract C2

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import { C1 } from './C1.sol';

contract C2 {
    C1 c1;
    constructor(address _c1) public {
        c1 = C1(_c1);
    }

    function setX(int _x) public {
        c1.setX(_x);
    }

    function getX() public view returns (int) {
        c1.getX();
    }
}
```

calling setX and getX on C1 works perfectly. But C2 methods don't work.
Tried on https://remix.ethereum.org/
Tried with solidity compiler 0.5.0 and EVM version constantinople.
I guess I am doing something wrong but not able to figure out what.

Edit: Add JS Code:

```
'use strict';

const web3 = require("web3");
const solc = require("solc");
const fs = require("fs");

const w3 = new web3(new web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("ws://***.***.***.***:8545"))

// compile contract
const contracts = {
    'C1.sol': {
        content: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/C1.sol", "utf-8")
    },
    'C2.sol': {
        content: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/C2.sol", "utf-8")
    }
}

const input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: contracts,
    settings: {
        optimizer: {
            enabled: false
        },
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': ["abi", "evm.bytecode"]
            }
        }
    }
}

const parsedOutput = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));

const compiled = {};
for (let contract in contracts) {
    const name = contract.split(".")[0];
    const output = {};
    output.abi = parsedOutput.contracts[contract][name].abi;
    output.bin = parsedOutput.contracts[contract][name].evm.bytecode.object;
    compiled[name] = output;
}

// console.log(compiled);

// deploy contract

const init = async () => {
    const addresses = await w3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log(addresses);

    const sendObj = {
        from: addresses[0],
        gas: 450000000
    };
    const callObj = {
        from: addresses[0]
    }

    // deploy C1
    const ct1 = new w3.eth.Contract(compiled["C1"].abi);
    ct1.options.data = "0x" + compiled["C1"].bin;
    const ct1Deployed = await ct1.deploy().send(sendObj);
    console.log(ct1Deployed.options.address);

    const newCt1 = new w3.eth.Contract(compiled["C1"].abi, ct1Deployed.options.address);

    console.log(await newCt1.methods.getX().call(callObj));
    await newCt1.methods.setX(123).send(sendObj);
    console.log(await newCt1.methods.getX().call(callObj));

    // deploy C2
    const ct2 = new w3.eth.Contract(compiled["C2"].abi);
    ct2.options.data = "0x" + compiled["C2"].bin;
    const ct2Deployed = await ct2.deploy({ arguments: [ct1Deployed.options.address] }).send(sendObj);
    console.log(ct2Deployed.options.address);

    const newCt2 = new w3.eth.Contract(compiled["C2"].abi, ct2Deployed.options.address);

    console.log(await newCt2.methods.getX(ct1Deployed.options.address).call(callObj));
    // await newCt2.methods.setX(123).send(sendObj);
    // console.log(await newCt2.methods.getX().call(callObj));
}

init();
```

Comment: Are you passing the address of a valid `C1` instance when you deploy the `C2` instance?

Comment: yes ofcourse. I am updating my question with JS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the `return` keyword in `C2`.

```
function getX() public view returns (int) {
    return c1.getX();
}
```

Also, it's confusing to see a variable `y` in C1's getter, which seems to be there by mistake. Better remove it, like so:

```
function getX() public view returns (int) {
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it does work on remix now. Still can't get it to work on my quorum node. I have raised this issue with them. Thanks.